# Most efficient way to access binary files on ADLS from worker node in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-lake

I have deployed an Azure HDInsight cluster with rwx permissions for all directories on the Azure Data Lake Store that also serves as its storage account. On the head node, I can load e.g. image data from the ADLS with a command like:

```
my_rdd = sc.binaryFiles('adl://{}.azuredatalakestore.net/my_file.png')
```

Workers do not have access to the SparkContext's `binaryFiles()` function. I can use the `azure-datalake-store` Python SDK to load the file, but this seems to be much slower. I assume because it realizes none of the benefits of the association between the cluster and the ADLS.

Is there a faster way to load files from an associated ADLS on workers?

Further context if needed:

I am using PySpark to apply a trained deep learning model to a large collection of images. Since the model takes a long time to load, my ideal would be:

- Send each worker a partial list of image URIs to process (by applying `mapPartition()` to an RDD containing the full list)
- Have the worker load data for one image at a time for scoring with the model
- Return the model's results for the set of images

Since I don't know how to load the images efficiently on workers, my best bet at the moment is to partition an RDD containing the image byte data, which (I assume) is memory-inefficient and creates a bottleneck by having the head node do all of the data loading.

Comment: I am out for the weekend. If you'll find any answer helpful please accept it so the bounty automatically awarded. TIA!

Answer (score 1):

The primary storage of the HDInsight cluster is simply available as the HDFS root.

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/digdug/images/
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   1    digdug supergroup       4957 2017-01-24 07:59 /user/digdug/images/a.png
-rw-r--r--   1    digdug supergroup       4957 2017-01-24 07:59 /user/digdug/images/b.png
-rw-r--r--   1    digdug supergroup       1945 2017-01-24 08:01 /user/digdug/images/c.png
```

In pyspark:

```
rdd = sc.binaryFiles("/user/digdug/images")

def f(iterator):
    sizes = []
    for i in iterator:
        sizes.append(len(i[1]))
    return sizes

rdd.mapPartitions(f).collect()
```

outputs:

```
[4957, 4957, 1945]
```

Comment: Hi Alexandre, I think we're talking at cross purposes. I am trying to get to data in the Azure Data Lake Store root. The cluster data is stored in a subdirectory of ADLS. Is there a way to access that data without the 'adl://' URI, so that my workers can load files from ADLS themselves, without relying on the Spark context?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @mewahl? I have exactly the same issue (but with audio files)

Comment: Hi Thomas, On [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767986/when-do-binaryfiles-load-into-memory-when-mappartitions-is-used?rq=1), I was told that each worker would load its own set of assigned files if I used mapPartitions() on an RDD created with sc.binaryFiles as above. This may well be accurate, since [runtime scales near-inversely](https://github.com/Azure/Embarrassingly-Parallel-Image-Classification/blob/master/img/scoring/scaling.png) with the number of workers. So I suppose there was no need to more explicitly specify data loading by individual workers after all.